# How to change parent of widgets without rebuilding their states

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, I have widgets like:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) {
            const List<ColorfulBox> children = [ColorfulBox(), ColorfulBox()];

            return orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 
                const Row(children: children) : 
                const Column(children: children);            
          },
        ),
      );
}

class ColorfulBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorfulBox({super.key});

  @override
  State<ColorfulBox> createState() => _ColorfulBoxState();
}

class _ColorfulBoxState extends State<ColorfulBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: getRandomColor(),
      );
}

Color getRandomColor() {
  var generatedColor = Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length);
  return Colors.primaries[generatedColor];
}
```

Currently when I rotate the device, new state of `ColorfulBox` will be build what causes color change.

I was wondering how can I keep `ColorfulBox` state?
I tried adding keys differently named to `ColorfulBox` and also adding `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but none of those two ideas worked.

Comment: @Nagual with multiple ColorfulBox, it would not render, key cannot be the same for multiple elements in collection. Even though setting Key inside widget does not change anything comparing to adding it as optional parameter, what I tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your state of widget is not recreated, but the build function is executed again.

You need call `getRandomColor()` outside of the `build` method:
Use this code:

```
class ColorfulBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorfulBox({super.key});

  @override
  State<ColorfulBox> createState() => _ColorfulBoxState();
}

class _ColorfulBoxState extends State<ColorfulBox> {
  final _color=getRandomColor();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: _color,
      );
}

Color getRandomColor() {
  var generatedColor = Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length);
  return Colors.primaries[generatedColor];
}
```

**Update:**
Also you need to change your Row and Column widget to Flex widget, you can't move widgets from Column to Row (or reverse) without recreating.
So, change

```
return orientation == Orientation.portrait
    ? Row(children: children)
    : Column(children: children);
```

To

```
return Flex(
  direction: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
  children: children,
);
```

Comment: It does not work. Look at the snippet: https://gist.github.com/MJablonskiCodespot/c5ecfd7e686c7eb4793e8a607969ce40 I've added prints and every time I rotate device, state is reinitialized

Comment: @MichałJabłoński You can't move widgets from Column to Row (or reverse) without recreating. see the updated answer.

Comment: oh, that could be a solution, I'll try it later, thanks

Comment: Flex is solution to this case. It works flawlessly, thanks! I can now modify state internally and change orientation of widgets as well without rebuilding them!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the colors higher up, when you define the children List:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Color _getRandomColor() =>
    Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ColorfulBox> children = [
      ColorfulBox(key: Key("1"), color: _getRandomColor()),
      ColorfulBox(key: Key("2"), color: _getRandomColor()),
    ];

    return Scaffold(body: OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
        return orientation == Orientation.portrait
            ? Row(children: children)
            : Column(children: children);
      },
    ));
  }
}

class ColorfulBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorfulBox({super.key, required this.color});
  final Color color;
  @override
  State<ColorfulBox> createState() => _ColorfulBoxState();
}

class _ColorfulBoxState extends State<ColorfulBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build ${widget.key}");
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: widget.color,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That is most likely best solution for now. Just figured it out too. Thanks

Comment: But to be honest I consider stateful widget that can internally modify its states and the goal is to keep whole state instance alive